# Using Pathauto on Articles in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pathauto, drupal-path-aliases

In Drupal 7, I have a site with thousands of articles. I'm using taxonomies to sort my articles, and a view which uses a content filter to display the appropriate articles with the associated terms on certain pages. Standard functionality.

I've added the paths (standard), pathauto, and Token, so I think I have all I need. In my taxonomy, I've set it up like this:

```
fruits (/fruits)
- apples (/fruits/apples)
- bananas (/fruits/bananas)
- grapes (/fruits/grapes)
```

But all my articles are on my website at www.mysite.com/articlename. I want it to appear like www.mysite.com/fruit/banana/pies.

According to everyone everywhere, I can add the path under Articles on my path configuration page using `[term:parents:join-path]/[term:name]`.

However, I got an error:

```
The Pattern for all Article paths is using the following invalid tokens [term:parents:join-path], [term:name].
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get! It seems others are struggling with this on other forums, but don't have the same problem I do.

Am I missing a module, maybe? These tokens weren't in my list.

Comment: those token are available in token list when you are editing article ? also you can check this module https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter

Comment: If you're asking if they show in the list on the Pathauto configuration page (), then no, they're not available under Content Paths. They are available in the Taxonomy Term Paths section, but that's not the section I need to edit, I don't believe. The thing is that people are telling me to put these tokens in "Pattern for all Article paths" under Content Paths, but I can't. I don't know how to get those tokens.

Comment: maybe you can hook the saving action and use function token_replace to your field value

Comment: Ok. How would I do that? I'm new to Drupal. I've only been using it for a few weeks so I don't quite know what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case, I have a taxonomy field for category. An use this pattern

```
[node:field_your_taxonomy_field]/[node:title]
```